# How to make sticky tooltips with Jquery TipTip plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, sticky, tiptip

I am using Jquery TipTip plugin. If you know better plugin that way easy to use you can tell me. Okay now i am able to make it work. It displays tooltips very good. But i want to make sticky tooltips. I mean when you hover mouse over the object tooltip will be displayed and until person clicks the link i put inside tooltip ,so when person clicked the tooltip will be closed. Their documentation is zero so i couldn't solve it.

tiptip main page : http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Here how they say exit and enter

enter: callback function - Custom function that is run each time you mouseover an element with TipTip applied to it.

exit: callback function - Custom function that is run each time you mouseout of an element with TipTip applied to it.

How can i call function from tiptip source code inside body.

Comment: how can i call this function inside html body ? deactive_tiptip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the **keepAlive** option for the plugin? This keeps the tooltip on the screen until the user mouses out of the tooltip (rather than off the targeted object itself).

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this programatically. You would have to extend the plugin itself or remove the mouseout eventhandler.

Actually after rereading the documentation, you could try to prevent the tooltip from disappearing using the exit callback like so:

```
exit: function(){
  // prevent action code goes here
}
```

But I'm not sure if this would work. Looking at the source, you could modify the deactivate_tiptip() function. The third line is the one that hides the tooltip.

```
tiptip_holder.fadeOut(opts.fadeOut);
```

Comment: hey could you help me with this. it seems like you are experienced with jquery. yes we should modify the source code :D

Comment: Sorry...I didn't check the comments until today. I'd be glad to help if you still need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solution .

Also check Try [QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-tooltip-plugins/
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Check these http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/ options see button true or false .

```
$('#tipDiv')

         .qtip({
            content: {
               text: 'Something', 
               title: {
                  text: 'My Title',
                  button: true
               }
            },

         });
```

Comment: i see that they have override default title that is good. so how can i do sticky tooltips with using Qtip ?

Comment: what does it mean when you say sticky ? Like having exit ?

Comment: this Qtip is really really hard to use. i would rather solve problem with TipTip

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips check here "Speech Bubble Tips" see how they have close button .

Comment: really really hard to use qtip2